# vision.internal.disparityParser in MATLAB

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I am working with the computer Vision toolbox in MATLAB 2014b
there is a function for Semi-global Matching (SGM )
I am trying to generate a disparity map of a stereo images. However, the disparity range needs to be quite large for some experiments.

Here is the function call:

```
Dmap = disparity(I1 I2, 'BlockSize', 15, 'DisparityRange', [-2466,  2466]);
```

The problem is the DisparityRange is limited to be in the range of [-2464, 2464]. Thus, I am getting an error msg like this one bellow.

---

```
Error using disparity
The value of 'DisparityRange' is invalid. Expected DisparityRange to be an array with all of the values >
-2466.

Error in vision.internal.disparityParser (line 38)
parser.parse(varargin{:});

Error in disparity>parseOptionalInputs (line 264)
    r = vision.internal.disparityParser(imageSize, getDefaultParameters(),...

Error in disparity>parseInputs (line 244)
r = parseOptionalInputs(imageSize, varargin{:});

Error in disparity (line 137)
r = parseInputs(I1, I2, varargin{:});
```

---

My questions:
1. I could not find the function (vision.internal.disparityParser). Where is should be located.
2. I would like to modify the code to work for rainges beyond the specified limit. Is that possible?
3. For anyone who worked with the C++ version of the SGM function (OpenCV), does the same problem exist (i.e., the disparity range limits).

Thank you!
:)

Answer (score 0):

I could only answer the first question. The function vision.internal.disparityParser is located at $MATLAB/toolbox/vision/vision/+vision/+internal/disparityParser.m .